# Laravel cron not shooting on the given time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron

Hello Laravel cronjob is not shooting with the time give in following code

```
           $schedule->command('snippets:newsletter')
           ->dailyAt('16:00')->runInBackground();
```

But when I am running this command it's going perfect

```
$schedule->command('snippets:newsletter')
             ->everyMinute()->runInBackground();
```

Comment: This could be due to the server time configured incorrectly. Please change your system timezone or add timezone in your crontab. This could also be possible if your file ownership is not set to root. Try running `chown -R www-data:root ./` in your laravel directory after configuring timezone.

Comment: Did you check server timezone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing app time zone UTC in .env may resolve the issue 
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

then

PHP artisan config:clear

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have added an entry into your local system's crontab and that it is working correctly as described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#introduction .

Comment: i already mentioned in the question that below query is working perfect...